# Handling an exception in an ajax action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an ajax action in **Rails**:

```
def ajax_action1
    begin
      item = Model1.where(id: params[:id]).first
      if item
       #....
      else
        render json: { errors: ['Not found'] }, status: 404
      end
    rescue
      render json: { errors: ['Unexpected exception, try again later.'] }, status: 503
    end
  end
```

I wonder, is it sensible enough to have an action like this? Is there they better way of doing this out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rescue` keyword like this:

```
def ajax_action1
  item = Model1.where(id: params[:id]).first
  if item
    #....
  else
    render json: { errors: ['Not found'] }, status: 404
  end
rescue
  render json: { errors: ['Unexpected exception, try again later.'] }, status: 503
end
```

Method `def` can serve as a `begin` statement:

```
def ajax_action1
  ...
rescue
  ...
end
```